# Visual Studio Code tries to activate conda base even though it is not installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever i open the integrated terminal in VS Code it tries `conda activate base` before doing anything different. I didn't explicitly configure the editor to do so and don't have `conda` installed either.

[image]

Settings:

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden",
    "python.insidersChannel": "weekly",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
}
```

I must say, that at one point i **had** installed Miniconda, but uninstalled it later. The issue persists and i would want to know why that is.

I'm using Visual Studio Code Insiders

```sh
~ λ code-insiders -v
1.46.0-insider
d487078dc7fc1c276657cadb61b4f63833a8df55
x64
```

with [Microsofts Python-Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) on Arch Linux.

EDIT:

After reading @Kishor s comments i investigated the impact of the currently opened workspace on the behavior and it turns out, that the issue only persists, if there is an open workspace containing python files. When opening a python file solely, i can not reproduce the issue.

I can't find any configuration file that redirects the python interpreter for that workspace/ folder though!

EDIT 2:

In response to @Brett in the comments:

I have a local settings-file that corresponds to the opened workspace. Its contents are listed below.

`python.pythonPath` points to a local venv, but it wasn't generated using conda.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/tim/.virtualenvs/escaperoom/bin/python",
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

Comment: Did you check your .bashrc file once? Maybe the script to activate conda is there.

Comment: @Kishor thanks for your comment! Unfortunately that's not the case. The issue only holds true for the integrated terminal in vs-code. No such issue when opening a regular terminal.

Comment: Do you know which python interpreter the extension is using? It uses the first interpreter it finds in the system path. Type Python: Select Interpreter in command palette and see the interpreters available.

Comment: The first available interpreter was somehow tied to the opened workspace! When i close the workspace the issue ist gone. Might the interpreter be set in some local config file?

EDIT: There was a `.vscode/`-directory, that pointed `python.pythonPath` to a venv. However that venv wasn't associated with conda in any way!

Comment: Do you have `python.pythonPath` set at the user level? And have you tried deactivating the Python extension to make sure it's the cause? The Python extension will not activate unless you open a Python file, so simply having Python files wouldn't trigger anything.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment! I can confirm, that the issue doesn't persist, if i disable the python-extension.

Comment: @BrettCannon i edited my question to answer your question concerning `python.pythonPath`.

Comment: I'm not sure but try `crtl + shift + p` then by typing `python:` you will have various commands related to that see if you can get anything useful maybe try `python: Clear Workspace Interpreter Setting`

Comment: @skrrrt no, this didn't change it.

Comment: At this point I think you may have to file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python to try and sort out what's going on.

Comment: The command is used to activate the python environment. if you choose the virtual environment, which was created by python through 'python -m venv xxx' command. It will take this kind command: '.../.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1' to activate environment, and if you select the environment created by condo, it will take this command: 'conda activate base' to activate python environment. So, just select the environment created by python, such as a virtual environment. VSCode will remember your choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally solved it by uninstalling VS Code, deleting all configuration files and reinstalling.

Now when i have opened a python file and the current workspace contains a settings file with the correct python-interpreter the correct environment gets sourced.